# MySQL Error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

Please have a look at the below query..

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name,
Provider.Name,
"One" AS Income_Type,
One.`One_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
One.`One_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
One.`One_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
One.`One_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
One.`One_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
One.`One_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
"N/A" AS VAT,
One.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN One ON One.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio

UNION

SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name,
Provider.Name,
"Two" AS Income_Type,
Two.`Two_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
Two.`Two_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
Two.`Two_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
Two.`Two_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
Two.`Two_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
Two.`Two_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
Two.`Two_Vat` AS VAT,
Two.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN Two ON Two.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio

UNION

SELECT 
Three.`Date` AS 'Updated_Date',
Three.`Gross_Fee` AS 'Gross_Fee',
Three.`Three_E_Fee` AS 'E_Fee',
Three.`Three_Tax_Provision` AS 'Tax_Provision',
Three.`Three_Net_Income` AS 'Net_Income',
Three.`Three_Vat` AS 'VAT',
0.0 AS 'V_Fee',
0.0 AS 'I_Fee',
Client.Name AS 'Client_Name',
'Three' AS Income_Type,
Provider.Name AS 'Provider_Name'
FROM Three
INNER JOIN Three_Obs ON Three_Obs.`idThree_Obs` = Three.`idThree_Obs`
LEFT JOIN Client ON Three_Obs.`idClient` = Client.`idClient`
LEFT JOIN Provider ON Three_Obs.`idProvider` = Provider.`idProvider`
```

When I run this query, I am getting the error `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`. That is simply because of the last query, it does not have the  `SELECT Client_Portfolio.*`. Inside `Client_Portfolio` there are 2 columns, `idClient` and `idPortfolio`, I have no reason to join this to my last query, because it is not needed. However I tried to do join `Three_Obs.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient` just to see how it will be, and I got completely invalid results.

So how can I fix this issue? I have no need of `Client_Portfolio.*` in last query, but I need that query to be `UNION` with other 2.

Comment: I guess in last query this statement is creating problem `'Three' AS Income_Type,` check this once. This should be `Three.something`

Comment: The number of columns appears in the corresponding SELECT statements must be equal.
The columns appear in  the corresponding positions of each SELECT statement must have the same data type or at least convertible data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of columns has to match for a union statement you can add two dummy columns in the last statement and fix the order so it matches the other select statements in the union. Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
Client_Portfolio.idClient,
Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio,
Client.Name AS "Client_Name",
Provider.Name AS "Provider_Name",
"One" AS "Income_Type",
One.`One_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
One.`One_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
One.`One_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
One.`One_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
One.`One_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
One.`One_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
"N/A" AS "VAT",
One.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN One ON One.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio

UNION

SELECT 
Client_Portfolio.idClient,
Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio,
Client.Name AS "Client_Name",
Provider.Name AS "Provider_Name",
"Two" AS "Income_Type",
Two.`Two_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
Two.`Two_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
Two.`Two_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
Two.`Two_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
Two.`Two_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
Two.`Two_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
Two.`Two_Vat` AS "VAT",
Two.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN Two ON Two.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio

UNION

SELECT 
null AS idClient,
null AS idPortfolio,
Client.Name AS "Client_Name",
Provider.Name AS "Provider_Name",
"Three" AS "Income_Type",
Three.`Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
0.0 AS "V_Fee",
Three.`Three_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
0.0 AS "I_Fee",
Three.`Three_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
Three.`Three_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
Three.`Three_Vat` AS "VAT",
Three.`Date` AS "Updated_Date"
FROM Three
INNER JOIN Three_Obs ON Three_Obs.`idThree_Obs` = Three.`idThree_Obs`
LEFT JOIN Client ON Three_Obs.`idClient` = Client.`idClient`
LEFT JOIN Provider ON Three_Obs.`idProvider` = Provider.`idProvider`
```

Although, looking at what your query seems to do I think you could rewrite it to use joins at least for the common tables client and provider and reduce the query a bit.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Yeah, the column order matters too.